# CS0117 'ExcelPackage' no contiene una definición para 'LicenseContext'

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de pasar los datos de un archivo excel a datatable con c# pero al llegar a esta linea

```
ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath));
```

me pone este mensaje: CS0117 'ExcelPackage' no contiene una definición para 'LicenseContext'

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si quitas o comentas esa línea?